# Getting Uncaught TypeError: onKeyPress is not a function in React typescript functional component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: onKeyPress is not a function in React typescript functional component in console when ever I am giving input in textbox.

Unable to know what should be done fix this issue. My requirement is based on some condition I need to call someFunctionToDoSomeStuff on onKeyPress event otherwise it should behave normally. Though I am able to track event onKeyPress when using the same component from another component but I want to fix this issue. So please help.

```
interface TextBxIProps = {
onKeyPress?: (e: React.KeyBoardEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=> void
okFlag?:boolean
}

const MyTextBox<TextBxIProps> = ({onKeyPress, okFlag=true})=> {
    const someFunctionToDoSomeStuff = (e: React.KeyBoardEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=>{
    // this is working fine
}

return(
    <TextBoxComponent onKeyPress={(event)=> {
    if(okFlag){
        return someFunctionToDoSomeStuff(event)
    }
    else{
        return onKeyPress(event) // this giving issue I think but unable to figure how shoudl I fix it as I want to return  normal event onKeyPress on some condition
    }
})}/>
```

Comment: This is difficult to follow because your code isn't remotely valid TS...

Comment: Hi my requirement is mainly to achieve to call someFunctionToDoSomeStuff on some condition on onKeyPress event otherwise it should behave normally. In this course I am getting the error => Uncaught TypeError: onKeyPress is not a function . I think this line of code => return onKeyPress(event) is not working , but unable to figure what shoud I return then.

Comment: Your function is kinda long; I suspect the newlines and spacing may be causing the issue. Extract your long function into a separate variable `const handleKeyPres = (event) => {if (okFlag)....}` and then just call `<TextBoxComponent onKeyPress={handleKeyPress} />`

Comment: Purely from looking at your interface, it seems the `onKeyPress` function is optional. Maybe it's not being passed and you're getting `undefined`?

Answer (score 0):

`onKeyPress` is indeed not defined anywhere, so the error message is correct.

If *"it should behave normally"* means that you want native behaviour, **there is nothing you need to do**, i.e. you don't need to return anything (no need for an `else`). That's the default behaviour.

Only if you want to prevent the "normal behaviour" you need to explicitly instruct:

```js
event.preventDefault()
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your comment , I actually want to to call to call someFunctionToDoSomeStuff function on some condition flag on onKeyPress event  of the main component otherwise it should behave normally if that flag is not passed.

Comment: @SCM, something like `(event)=> { if (okFlag) someFunctionToDoSomeStuff(event); }` should be enough